# get value fetch pdo in tag HTML

Tags: php, html, pdo

how do I get data value when I echo data inside HTML tag?

```
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();   


    $query = "SELECT 
          po.no_po, 
          barang.nama_barang, 
          klien.nama_klien, 
          po.tgl_po, 
          po.qty, 
          barang.harga_jual, 
          po.status_po, 
          po.keterangan, 
          surat_pengantar.tgl_kirim, 
          gudang.nama_gudang,
           barang.harga_jual * po.qty AS total_harga
        FROM 
          public.po, 
          public.barang, 
          public.klien, 
          public.good_receipt, 
          public.gudang, 
          public.surat_pengantar
        WHERE 
         po.no_po = ?   
          po.id_barang = barang.id_barang AND
          po.id_klien = klien.id_klien AND
          po.no_po = surat_pengantar.no_po AND
          po.no_po = good_receipt.no_po AND
          gudang.id_gudang = good_receipt.id_gudang";

  $stmt = $db->prepare( $query );
  $stmt->bindParam(1,$no_po);
  $stmt->execute();
?> 

   <body>
    <?php
    $no=1;
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $no_po = $row['no_po'];
    $nama_barang = $row['nama_barang'];
    $nama_klien = $row['nama_klien'];
    $tgl_po = $row['tgl_po'];
    $harga_jual = $row['harga_jual'];
    $qty = $row['qty'];
    $total_harga = $row['total_harga'];
    $status_po = $row['status_po'];
    $keterangan = $row['keterangan'];
    $nama_gudang = $row['nama_gudang'];
    $tgl_po = $row['tgl_po']; */
    $no++;
   ?>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <h1>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/tahirtaous">
            <img src="YSU.png">
            Logo here
            </a>
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
          <h1>Purchase Order</h1>
          <h1><small><?php echo $no_po;?></small></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-5">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4>From: <a href="#">Your Name</a></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>
                Address <br>
                details <br>
                more <br>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-2 text-right">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4>Detail Invoice</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <table border="0">
              <tr>
              <td>Tanggal PO</td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td><?php echo $tgl_po;?></td>
              </tr>

               <tr>
              <td>Gudang</td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td><?php echo $nama_gudang?></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
              <td>Nama Pelanggan</td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td><?php echo $nama_klien?></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
              <td>Status Purchase Order</td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td><?php echo $status_po?></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
              <td>Tanggal Kirim</td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td><?php echo $tgl_kirim?></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
              <td>Mata Uang</td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td>IDR(Rp)</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
              <td>Term Pembayaran</td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td>30 hari</td>
              </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- / end client details section -->

      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th>
              <h4>No.item</h4>
            </th>
            <th>
              <h4>Nama barang</h4>
            </th>
            <th>
              <h4>Quantity</h4>
            </th>
            <th>
              <h4>Price</h4>
            </th>
            <th>
              <h4>Keterangan</h4>
            </th>
            <th>
              <h4>Sub Total</h4>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $no?></td>
            <td><?php echo $nama_barang?></td>
           <td><?php echo $qty?></td>
            <td class='text-right'><?php echo $harga_jual?></td>
            <td class='text-right'><?php echo $keterangan?></td>
            <td class='text-right'><?php echo $total_harga?></td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      <div class="row text-right">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-8">
          <p>
            <strong>
            Total : <br>
            </strong>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <strong>
          Rp<?php echo $total_harga?> <br>

          </strong>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>


</body>
</html>
```

If I remove no_po = :no_po from my query, the result just get the value from one no_po, meanwhile I want the result exist based on no_po.
I declared variable but echo data inside tag HTML doesn't works. The result should get value based on no_po. 
Could anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Does the one row you are getting in the result have the value for no_po that you are searching for in the query?

Comment: yes. it's because $_GET['no_po']. if i remove it, none result show @DAB

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into a LEFT JOIN somewhere. What's could be happening is that with all the joins you are using implicitly, the row which you are looking for that does exist, is already being ruled out by the joins. Implicit joins are inner joins and inner joins require all tables to be present with the matching values. So if all the tables are able to join except for your last one 'surat_pengantar', it will nullify the result from the first table that matched on no_po. This is because your condition of po.no_po = surat_pengantar.no_po is false.

Comment: sorry, but if i dont write po.no_po=surat_pengantar.no_po, the result of query will be repeat.